# Plotting a log-log scale, log-binned network degree distributions on NetworkX

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, networkx, scientific-computing

Trying to make a log-log scale log binned plot. Wondering if someone can give me some advice on how to approach this problem. Thanks.

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import powerlaw

G = nx.Graph()
G = nx.read_edgelist('data.txt', create_using=nx.DiGraph, nodetype = int)

M = nx.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(G)
xmin = min([d[1] for d in G.degree()])
indegrees = M.sum(0).A[0]
degree = np.bincount(indegrees)
fit = powerlaw.Fit(np.array(degree)+1, fit_method='KS')
    
    
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6)) 

plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
plt.plot(range(len(degree)),degree,'b.')   
plt.loglog()
plt.xlim((min(degree), max(degree)))
plt.xlabel('Degree')
plt.ylabel('P(k)')
plt.show()
```

What I current have

[image]

What I am trying to get

[image]

Comment: Could you expand what you are trying to do? Because what you are trying to get is basically what you have...

Comment: @AveragePythonEnjoyer
I am trying to get is the log-log plot of degree distribution using logarithmic binning visible in red. What I currently have visible from my plot is a log-log plot with linear binning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scaled logarithmic binning in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170511/scaled-logarithmic-binning-in-python)